# openpyxl: how to fit a chart inside a single cell?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

The problem is: column.width, row.height and chart.width, chart.height use different units. Also it seems it might depend on the os, application and display. Is it even possible to fit a chart inside a single cell so it gonna be rendered the same everywhere?

UPD: The code looks like

```
width = 26
height = 78

for c in range(ws.min_column, ws.max_column + 1):
    ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(c)].width = width

for r in range(ws.min_row, 10):
    ws.row_dimensions[r+1].height = height

chart.width = width / 5.425
chart.height = height / 29
```

Comment: In general; yes you could fit a chart in a single cell. However perhaps it would be better if you could explain what rendering issue(s) you have.

Comment: @moken if I open the same file, let's say, in LibreOffice and Office365, a chart size differs, it usually has the same height, but width is different. So in one app chart is perfectly fitted in a cell, and in another it's a bit smaller that cell. 

Code in UPD section gives a perfect match in Office365 but not in LibreOffice

Comment: This is not a direct answer. But may be try https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_sparklines.html.

Comment: @najeem thanks a lot, that's interesting, but it's definitely not related to the question and also sparklines seem to not support gridlines, which is not suitable for my needs

Comment: I know you need to do this programmatically but interested to know; If you manually size the chart area using the ALT key and mouse to 'snap to grid' on both row and column grid lines does that fix the variation in sizing across applications? Chart properties being set to the default 'Move and size with cells'.

Comment: i cannot reproduce the problem with the code given:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example